# Add italic font and link into a SMS using Android APP

Tags: android, formatting, sms

I want to add some italic font and links into SMS using an android app. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Links is doable (infact is probably supported. Check ***Linkify***)

Are you looking to build a SMS Application? If so,then for Italics/Bold etc...You could format your SMS as an HTML Message and send it...

Within Your SMS Application, you could Make use of the HTML format and display it with formatting, but on other SMS applications it'll end up displaying RAW Html code.

So this will work only on your SMS Application (or perhaps any other who will support HTML SMSes)